# why dmidecode said my server memory max capacity is 16G. in fact slots are consist of 8G+2G+2G+2G memory

Tags: linux

in Summary:
server now has **14G** memory, which consist of 4 slots (2G+2G+2G+**8G**)
since it got a max memory in one slot are **8G** , why max capacity is 16G ,rather than **8*4=32G**

here are details:

klg@gentoo:~$ free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         14022      12270       1751          0         45       7189
```

klg@gentoo:~$ sudo dmidecode -t 17
    [sudo] password for klg:

```
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: DIMM_A1 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 019800000000
    Serial Number: 5D3BFD38
    Asset Tag: 04105200
    Part Number: 9965413-011.A00LF 
    Rank: 2

Handle 0x1101, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 1
    Locator: DIMM_A2 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: 019800000000
    Serial Number: F72AA08D
    Asset Tag: 04144700
    Part Number: 9965525-116.A00LF 
    Rank: 2

Handle 0x1102, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: DIMM_A3 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 019800000000
    Serial Number: 5E3B4C08
    Asset Tag: 04105200
    Part Number: 9965413-011.A00LF 
    Rank: 2

Handle 0x1103, DMI type 17, 28 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: DIMM_A4 
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1333 MHz
    Manufacturer: 019800000000
    Serial Number: 6D3ACDE3
    Asset Tag: 04105200
    Part Number: 9965413-011.A00LF 
    Rank: 2
```

update:
using DELL R210
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/PowerEdgeR210TechGuide_04052010.pdf
after reading the guide, found out :

```
System Capacity|System Memory Speed|DIMM Speed|DIMM_T ECH|DIMM Capacity |NUM_DI MM|Slot|NUM_Rank|Data Width
8GB 1333 1333 UDIMM 4 2 1,2 2 X8
16GB 1066 1066 UDIMM 4 4 1,2,3,4 2 X8
```

** seems max should be 16Gx4=32G, at 1066MHZ **

klg@gentoo:~$ sudo dmidecode -t 16
[sudo] password for klg: 
    # dmidecode 2.11
    SMBIOS 2.6 present.

```
Handle 0x1000, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4
```

**Maximum Capacity: 16 GB** , seems weird.
OS, using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: What server is it and what do the manufacturers specs say ?

Comment: @lain add some update.